# How to debug push notifications for IOS?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, ionic-framework

I have setup ionic push for Android and IOS, the android version works great, but the IOS doesn't.
I have setup the provisioning and certificate files on IOS and they seem to be fine.

Also, the tokens get generated fine, and if i do a test with ionic push -s or CURL i can see the request going through with no errors that i can tell, just that the notifications don't show on the device.

I made the IOS package using the Phonegap Build service, not sure if that's an issue.

So, i guess my question is if there is a way for me to debug and figure out what went wrong.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also suffered a lot in push notification.

Finally i got some solution. it might be helpful for you
If u get device token from APNS server and notification send without any error but still you not getting notification in device then problem is in certificate.

Useful Links:

1) For Troubleshooting Push Notifications is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)
2) Tutorial for generating generating certificate and send push notification is [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: it seems you were right. the only thing is that i only needed to keep the production certificate and not the development one

Comment: development certificate also works but you need to keep everything in development mode.

Comment: true, I've noticed that as well. the only other issue is that not all notifications go through, just some... android works excellent though